# Object reference not set to an instance of an object while the same method worked before

Tags: c#

I am using Visual studio 2010 with c# and SQL Management studio.

I am working on the mailbox feature.

I written a method for if a user click for reply button the content for reply is like this..

```
private string adjustContentForReply(List<Guid> sender)
    {
        string content = string.Empty;
        messageID = (Guid)Session["messageID"];

        //haal de ontvangers uit de database van het bericht
        List<Guid> receivers = m.bussinesCollection.BussinesMessageReceiver.GetReceivers(messageID);

        //pas de inhoud van het bericht aan met de details van het vorige bericht
        content = "<br /><br />----------------------------------------<br />";
        content += "Ontvangen op: " + m.bussinesCollection.BussinesMessageReceiver.GetMessageReceiver(messageID, boxOwner).DateReceived.ToString() + "<br />";
        content += "Onderwerp: " + m.bussinesCollection.BussinesMessage.GetMessageSubject(messageID) + "<br />";
        content += "Van: " + m.bussinesCollection.BussinesPerson.GetFullName(sender[0]) + "<br />";
        content += "Aan: ";

        //Voeg één of meerdere ontvangers toe aan details
        foreach (Guid rec in receivers)
        {
            content += m.bussinesCollection.BussinesPerson.GetFullName(rec);
            if (receivers.Count() > 1)
                content += "; ";
        }
        content += "<br />";
        content += "----------------------------------------<br /><br />";

        //voeg de inhoud van het vorige bericht aan de content
        content += m.bussinesCollection.BussinesMessage.GetMessageContent(messageID);

        return content;
    }
```

It is giving me error in line

```
content += "Ontvangen op: " + m.bussinesCollection.BussinesMessageReceiver.GetMessageReceiver(messageID, boxOwner).DateReceived.ToString() + "<br />";
```

the erroe is

**Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

the GetMessageReceiver() is like this

```
public MessageReceiver GetMessageReceiver(Guid msgId, Guid personId)
        {
            var message = from msg in Db.MessageReceivers
                          where msg.MessageID.Equals(msgId) && msg.ReceiverID.Equals(personId)
                          select msg;

          return  message.Count().Equals(1) ? message.First() : null;
        }
```

when I debugged it and taken the messageId and BoxOwnerId and fire a query in Database,it shows two rows for the given combination.

can any one help me?

Hey the problem is solved from there and now i can create a message for reply.
But on clicking on the send button page the same error now thrown there.

Comment: shouldn't it be `message.Count().MoreThan(1)` or something like that (instead of `Equals(1)`)?

Comment: @Default it does not make any difference

Comment: Offtopic: You could look into using the `StringBuilder`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the error because you're not checking the return value of `GetMessageReceiver()`. You either need to make sure that `GetMessageReceiver` cannot return `null`, or you need to check the return value before using any functions on it

```
MessageReceiver receiver = m.bussinesCollection.BussinesMessageReceiver.GetMessageReceiver(messageID, boxOwner);
if (receiver == null)
    // handle error
    return;

content += "Ontvangen op: " + receiver.DateReceived.ToString() + "<br />";
```

Answer (score 3):

You want to have

```
return message.First();
```

instead of

```
return  message.Count().Equals(1) ? message.First() : null;
```

Your code returns `null` if there is more than one result. And you say, that you have two rows in the database for the IDs you supplied, so you are getting `null`...

You should be using `First` and not `FirstOrDefault`, because your code is structured in a way that only works correctly, if your message always returns a reference that is not `null`.

Comment: If that's the case, I'd be more concerned with why there are messages with duplicate IDs in the database.

Comment: @Rawling: If *what* is the case?

Comment: If the case is that the null reference exception is due to the code returning `null` instead of the first email when more than one email matches. (Which admittedly it does say in the question if I finish reading it...)

Comment: @Rawling: Yes, it says so in the question. Whether that's correct or not is a different question. I agree though, it doesn't look right.

Comment: @Rawling You may be right. But i can't find the reason for duplicate messageid and personid..

Comment: Yes: Fail fast, fail early. This will produce a better error message.

Answer (score 1):

If you get a NullReferenceException on that line:

```
content += "Ontvangen op: " + m.bussinesCollection.BussinesMessageReceiver.GetMessageReceiver(messageID, boxOwner).DateReceived.ToString() + "<br />";
```

then the `null` could almost be anywhere. 
Except in this case: apparently there are no nulls in `m.bussinesCollection.BussinesMessageReceiver` or you would have gotten the error a few lines earlier.

So either `GetMessageReceiver` or `DateReceived` is null.

You do know that your GetMessageReceiver method returns null if there are not exactly 1 messages (so 0 or >=2)?